# Clustering Weblogic JMS

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have 8 instances of Weblogic, dispatched on 4 machines. Those 8 instances are grouped in a cluster.
Those 8 instances are great for EJB containers, but I have also 8 instances of Weblogic JMS server. In consequence, all my JMS messages are dispatched on those 8 instances...
My volume is too low to need so many JMS servers. I'd like to have only one JMS Weblogic instance by machine.
Is it possible to disable JMS Messaging on some instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can target your JMS Server to an individual WL Server within the cluster. See [the theory](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jms_admin/basic_config.html#wp1105995) and [console help](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/jms_servers/TargetAndDeployJMSServers.html) for instructions.

You dont need 8 JMS Servers, just keep 1 and use a Migratable Target so that it takes care of failover for you.

Answer (score 0):

You target JMS servers to individual managed servers.  What you can do is to target the JMS servers to only one of the managed servers running on each of your machines.

However, you need to be careful about targeting your applications and MDBs, for example, to make sure they can bind to the JNDI names of the required queues.  Otherwise you're going to get errors in your stdout and log files that will clutter them up.